# Web print service

Tags: printing, services

Is there some sevices wich can connect my printer directly through internet to this service and than i can, for example, share this printer to my friend?

Comment: not programming related

Answer (score 1):

[PrinterShare](http://www.printeranywhere.com/) appears to offer what you're looking for.  I've never tried it before, though, so your mileage may vary...

Answer (score 0):

why not build a vpn connection between you and your friend? then you can share printers like on a local network.

Comment: cause this is too complicated to manage if you have 15 friends who do not understand what is vpn is )

Comment: Printershare LOOKS good Thanks. If I have problems, I'll share.